# How to cite musical score in Turabian given the following options?

Tags: citations

I am trying to cite a hard copy of a musical score, using Microsoft Word's References feature.

Word gives me several options. I have narrowed it down to a few but none of them explicitly say "Musical score".

- Book
- Book Section
- Journal Article
- Report
- Art
- Sound Recording
- Performance
- Film

There's also a "miscellaneous", but I'm not sure if I should categorize musical score under that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A musical score is cited like a **book** in this style.

Here's an example from [Depauw University Libraries](http://libguides.depauw.edu/content.php?pid=16848&sid=113582) -

The footnote is in the form

> Composer First Name Last, *Name of Musical Work* 
>   (City, State: Publisher, Year).

e.g.,

> Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart, *Eine kleine Nachthmusik*, K. 525
>   (Bryn Mawr, PA:  Theodore Presser, 1960).

The bibliography is in the form

> Composer Last Name, First.  *Name of Musical Work*.
>                   City, State (if city isn't well known): Publisher, Year.

e.g.,

> Mozart, Wolfgang Amadeus.  *Eine kleine Nachtmusik*, K. 525.
>                   Bryn Mawr, PA:  Theodore Presser, 1960.

(The [Depauw site](http://libguides.depauw.edu/content.php?pid=16848&sid=113582) has additional information on various special cases.)

Comment: Caveat: This applies if the work being cited is the only item published in the book in question. If it's a shorter score in a collection, then __Book Section__ should be used instead.

Comment: @aeismail that's covered in the link mentioned at the end :)

Comment: Yeah, it was a musical score on its own. Thanks!